# Why I get empty file after sed -e?

Tags: bash, sed, cat

given the following file `file`:

```
my name is: @NAME@
```

I ran this script:

```
name="Alin"
full_file="$(mktemp)"
cat file | \
    sed -e "s:@NAME@:${name}:g" | \
    >> "${full_file}"

cat "${full_file}"
```

but i get empty file (the `${full_file}`) and i don't understand why..
I expectes to see this file as result:

```
my name is: Alin
```

What I missing here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but i don't read (with cat) and write (with sed) to the same file..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I read with cat command from `file` and write with sed to tmp file

Comment: Right, replace last ``| \`` with ``\`` (or remove this and put the ``>> "${full_file}"`` on the same line with `sed` command). The `>>` should follow the `sed` command directly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please explain more about that ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why the `>>` should follow the `sed` command directly ?

Comment: Just run `cat file | > s` and you will get an empty `s` file. And `cat file > s` will populate `s`.

Comment: c.f. [Useless Use of `cat`](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you redirect nothing to the new temporary file since the `>>` appears after the pipe.

You need to remove the pipe after the `sed` command:

```bash
name="Alin"
full_file="$(mktemp)"
cat file | \
    sed -e "s:@NAME@:${name}:g" \
    >> "${full_file}"

cat "${full_file}"
```

Or, simply put the `>> "${full_file}"` on the `sed` line:

```bash
name="Alin"
full_file="$(mktemp)"
cat file | \
    sed -e "s:@NAME@:${name}:g" >> "${full_file}"

cat "${full_file}"
```

Or, since there is no point using `cat` pipe to `sed` here (mind that you can always pass the file name directly to the `sed` command):

```bash
name="Alin"
full_file="$(mktemp)"
sed -e "s:@NAME@:${name}:g" file >> "${full_file}"
cat "${full_file}"
```

Comment: ... and the code would be a little clearer if the OP used `>` instead of `>>`. Using `>>` makes readers spend time trying to figure out why they're appending....

Comment: @EdMorton-SOstopbullying We do not know what OP is actually doing, so I'd stick with the current code. Yes, `>` would (re-)create a file.

Comment: The braces are also kind of distracting; taking them out will not change the meaning of the code at all.